# Is there a way to Name a specific Chrome Window on startup?

Tags: google-chrome, window, rename, command-line-arguments, application-launch

I would like to be able to open chrome, either by clicking on the chrome.exe or by clicking on a URL, and as a result, chrome would launch with a specific window name.

I just want to have my chrome window be named something like "Chrome Window" on startup.

Comment: Which system are you on--Linux, Windows, Mac, ChromeOS?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I should have mentioned that. I am on Windows 11 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this flag on the command line or link file:

```
--window-name="Chrome Window"
```